# What does a sentence starting with "pas" mean?

Tags: négation

I was looking at an Air Bnb posting and the host said

> House rules | Pas d'arrivée après 22h.

Does this mean "no arrivals before 22h" or "no arrivals after 22h"?

To my (very limited) knowledge, "pas" is meant to be used in conjunction with "ne" ("ne X pas") - I've never seen it without before - is this a slang/colloquial way of using it?

Comment: *no arrivals after 22h*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Pas*** can be taken here as the second term of a split negative where the first part is not expressed but just implicit. You might interpret the sentence as:

> [Il n'y a] **pas d'arrivée après 22h.**

or better:

> [Nous n'acceptons] **pas d'arrivée après 22h.**

This is not slang/colloquial but standard and common French.

Answer (score 4):

> Pas d'arrivée après 22h : no arrivals *after* 22h

*Pas*, utilisé sans le *ne* indique la négation de ce qui suit et a ici le sens de :

> *Aucune* arrivée après 22 heures.

Cette expression se lit souvent sur les pancartes, ou dans les règlements :

> *Pas d'arrivée* est une forme impérative pour inciter poliment et fermement à *ne pas* faire quelque chose ; on l'écrit pour que tout le monde en prenne connaissance.
>
> *N'arrivez pas* est une forme comminatoire beaucoup plus agressive, c'est un ordre ; on le dit (parfois on le hurle) pour prévenir d'un danger ou d'une contrainte.

Answer (score 0):

The "pas" means "no".

The exact translation is "No" arrivals after 22h.